# Red underline on few activities in manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

[As shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udm1q.png)

I am getting red underline in some of the activities in manifest file. Due to this, my application's apk is crashing every time I am downloading it on my phone. If i am connecting the device directly using usb, app is running perfectly. But when i build it's apk, it crashes when I launch my second activity i.e. ApplicationSelection.java, I have no clue why is this happening. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error/warning when you mouse over the red underlined activity names?  Isn't this the first thing you should check?

Comment: Mouse hover there at first.

Comment: What error or crash you are getting?? Share logs.

Comment: Solved the issue after inspection. It was because i didn't declare my classes as public.